# latest distinct record from partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with information like this

```
VehicleID | dtDate | Lat | long
```

A new record is created every so often with new lat and long for the same vehicleID, I am trying to get the latest Date per vehicle so my lat and long would be the latest.

```
select row_number over (partition by vehicleID order by dtDate), 
 vehicleID, 
 Lat,
 Long
from database.schema.table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH   vehicleCTE
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vehicleID ORDER BY dtDate DESC) AS rowNum,
               vehicleID,
               Lat,
               Long,
               dtDate
        FROM   t1)
SELECT vehicleID,
       Lat,
       Long,
       dtDate
FROM   vehicleCTE
WHERE  rowNum = 1;
```

Comment: No problem, I have edited your question and added **sql-server** tag

Comment: @user1552172, if the answer helped, mark it as so to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a CTE here if this is just an adhoc query:

```
WITH CTE1
AS (
    SELECT vehicleID
        ,Lat
        ,Long
        ,row_number OVER (
            PARTITION BY vehicleID ORDER BY dtDate DESC
            ) AS latestdate
    FROM MyTable
    )
SELECT vehicleID
    ,Lat
    ,Long
FROM CTE1
WHERE latestdate = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the top record from your query, you can use the following query

```
WITH cte 
AS
(
select row_number() over 
    (partition by vehicleID order by dtDate DESC) as RowNum
    , vehicleID, Lat,Long
from database.schema.table
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE RowNum=1;
```